# Using a dictionaries to filter a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Is there a way to use a combination of a column names and a values dictionary to filter a pandas dataframe?

Example dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "name": ["Ann", "Jana", "Yi", "Robin", "Amal", "Nori"],
    "city": ["Chicago", "Prague", "Shanghai", "Manchester", "Chicago", "Osaka"],
    "age": [28, 33, 34, 38, 31, 37],
    "score": [79.0, 81.0, 80.0, 68.0, 61.0, 84.0],
})

column_dict = {0:"city", 1:"score"}
value_dict = {0:"Chicago", 1:61}
```

The goal would be to use the matching keys column and value dictionaries to filter the dataframe.
In this example, the city would be filtered to Chicago and the score would be filtered to 61, with the filtered dataframe being:

```
    name    city    age score
4   Amal    Chicago 31  61.0
```

Comment: `df[(df[column_dict.values()] == value_dict.values()).all(axis=1)]`

Answer (score 1):

```
keep_rows = pd.Series(True, index=df.index)
for k, col in column_dict.items():
    value = value_dict[k]
    keep_rows &= df[col] == value

>>> df[keep_rows]
   name     city  age  score
4  Amal  Chicago   31   61.0
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit funny to use two different dicts to store keys and values. You're better off with something like this:

```
filter_dict = {"city":"Chicago", "score":61}

df_filt = df
    for k,v in filter_dict.items():
        df_filt = df_filt[df_filt[k] == v]
```

output:

```
   name     city  age  score
4  Amal  Chicago   31   61.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html):

```
# create filter DataFrame from column_dict and value_dict
df_filter = pd.DataFrame({value: [value_dict[key]] for key, value in column_dict.items()})

# use merge with df_filter
res = df.merge(df_filter, on=['city', 'score'])

print(res)
```

**Output**

```
   name     city  age  score
0  Amal  Chicago   31   61.0
```